# Custom message pump for MessageBox (Windows)?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

I have a large code base where there are lots of calls to `AfxMessageBox(...)`. What I need to do is while these messageboxes are modal service some external IO (i.e. a network communication).

I've considered writing a custom CDialog and my own message pump - but I'm unsure of how to make the CDialog generic enough that I can reliably create all the messageboxes without having to test them all.

Alternatively I've been looking at hooking into the messageboxes' windproc function through `SetWindowsHookEx` but this has the limitation that it happens after the messagepump and will not fire if there are no messages for that dialog.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to acheive this or if either of my two approaches above are worth pursuing. ?

Comment: Just don't.  Use a thread or a timer.

Comment: You are trying to find a fix your problem from the wrong end. Decouple your I/O and GUI, and you'll see your issues go away. Besides, a modal loop should not get in your way even when your I/O reports events through custom messages (`WM_APP + x`). Are you using messages in the wrong range, e.g. `WM_USER + x` instead?

Comment: @IInspectable My IO is using PostThreadMessage which I've now realised is being swallowed by my Modal loop. I hope the solution here might help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050428-00/?p=35753

Comment: Right, thread messages do get lost, when modal message loops run (keep in mind, that modal message loops also run, when moving/resizing a window, or when navigating a menu). If you can change the code you might want to use `PostMessage` instead, and create a (message-only) window to handle them (although a message filter hook may just work fine, if done right).

Comment: "there are lots of calls to AfxMessageBox(...)" — You have a severe usability issue. Isn't the user bombarded with message popups all the time?

Comment: @sergiol I guess I mean to say there are lots of places where `AfxMessageBox(..)` is called rather than its called lots of times.